# Wsgen cannot produce wsdl that uses com.sun.xml.ws.developer.StreamingAttachment

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsgen

I'm having a very weird issue with a jax-ws web service class that we use. When I deploy the application on Tomcat, it properly generates the .wsdl file and I can access it from `localhost:8080/server/MyWebservice?wsdl`. However if I try to generate the file using the `wsgen` tool provided by the jdk with `-verbose` parameter it fails with the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Annotation @com.sun.xml.ws.developer.StreamingAttachment(dir=, memoryThreshold=500000, parseEagerly=true) is not recognizable, at least one constructor of class com.sun.xml.ws.developer.StreamingAttachmentFeature should be marked with @FeatureConstructor

I checked the StreamingAttachmentFeature class and it **does** have a constructor annotated with `@FeatureConstructor`. Those classes are inside the `jaxws-rt.jar` which I also declare as a dependency. The only thing I'm afraid of is if those classes are also declared from another jar dependency and something gets mixed up but it seems very unlikely...